# Getting size of a structure in GAE/Go

Tags: google-app-engine, memory, go, sizeof

I would like to get the size of a structure in GAE/Go.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338588/generic-function-to-get-size-of-any-structure-in-golang) post and wrote the code as below.

```
import (
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func GetSize(T interface{}) {
    size := reflect.TypeOf(T).Size()
    return int((*int)(unsafe.Pointer(size)))
}
```

But this code does not work because GAE does not allow to import `unsafe`.

How can I do this in GAE/Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution is not valid code, it has multiple errors.

For example `GetSize()` has no result type, so you couldn't return anything.

Next, the expression you return is also a syntax error, it attempts to convert an `*int` pointer to `int` which is not valid.

You need to dereference the pointer first, so the correct syntax would be:

```
func GetSize(T interface{}) int {
    size := reflect.TypeOf(T).Size()
    return int(*(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(size)))
}
```

**But.** It makes no sense. [`reflect.Type.Size()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) already returns the size (the number of bytes needed to store a value of the given type), so there is no need of that `unsafe` magic. What may be confusing is that its return type is `uintptr`, but you may simply use that value after converting it to `int` for example.

Simply use:

```
func GetSize(v interface{}) int {
    return int(reflect.TypeOf(v).Size())
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println("Size of int:", GetSize(int(0)))
fmt.Println("Size of int64:", GetSize(int64(0)))
fmt.Println("Size of [100]byte:", GetSize([100]byte{}))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vaKGKyMuFp)):

```
Size of int: 4
Size of int64: 8
Size of [100]byte: 100
```

One thing you must not forget: this `GetSize()` will not recurisvely examine the size of the passed value. So for example if it's a struct with a pointer field, it will not "count" the size of the pointed value, only the size of the pointer field.

Constructing a `GetSize()` that recurisvely counts the total size of a complex data structure is non-trivial due to types like `map`. For details, see [How to get variable memory size of variable in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257522/how-to-get-variable-memory-size-of-variable-in-golang/44258164#44258164)